# jQuery Selector with Node.js returns differently to Node-less jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm attempting to use JSTree in a Node.js project. JSTree requires a jQuery element and in my pre-node implementation I got this by using the jQuery selector:

```
$("#ID").jstree(...)
```

To make this work with node, I've declared

```
var $ = require("jquery")
```

However, when the selector returns instead of a jQuery element I get `r.fn.init(1)`. It contains the same DOM element as the jQuery element returned by the selector before using node so it is finding it okay.

My issue is I need the jQuery element to use with JSTree so this isn't good enough, how do I get the jQuery element in this situation?